# jquery: get id from class selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way that I can get the id of an element from something like:

```
<a href="#" class="test" id="test_1">Some text</a>
<a href="#" class="test" id="test_2">Some text</a>
<a href="#" class="test" id="test_3">Some text</a>
```

and then I bind

> $('.test')

so when I click one of the elements I get back the id?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Doh.. If I get you right, it should be as simple as:

```js
$('.test').click(function() {
  console.log(this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="test" id="test_1">Some text</a>
<a href="#" class="test" id="test_2">Some text</a>
<a href="#" class="test" id="test_3">Some text</a>
```

You can just *access* the *id property* over the underlaying *dom node*, within the event handler.

Answer (score 47):

Use "attr" method in jquery.

```
$('.test').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Comment: The underlying question: Once you've got `this`, you don't really need the `id`, assuming the OP is trying to find the element by its ID, rather than the ID by the element...

Comment: That's right. However, he may want to display the name of id.

Comment: I agree with both, it all depends on your particular task! :)

Comment: `selected.id` would return undefined for me but `selected.attr('id')` worked fine.

Answer (score 8):

When you add a click event, `this` returns the element that has been clicked. So you can just use `this.id`;

```
$(".test").click(function(){
   alert(this.id); 
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/rfbrp/

Answer (score 8):

As of jQuery 1.6, you could (and some would say should) use **.prop** instead of .**attr**

```
$('.test').click(function(){
    alert($(this).prop('id'));
});
```

It is discussed further in this post: [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Answer (score 4):

Be careful if you use fat arrow functions as you will get undefined for this.id
Wasted 10 minutes today wondering what the hell was going on

Comment: What is Fat Arrow Functions?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Arrow_functions

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".class").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

only on jquery button click we can do this class should be written there

Answer (score 0):

Nothing from this examples , works for me

```
for (var i = 0; i < res.results.length; i++) {
        $('#list_tags').append('<li class="dd-item" id="'+ res.results[i].id + '"><div class="dd-handle root-group">' + res.results[i].name + '</div></li>');
}

    $('.dd-item').click(function () {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    });
```