# how to get element attributes (i.e id,name,style,etc) values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have no idea what what to do. Actually i need id of the control(element/tag),

when key up on any control .
if more attributes(name,style,etc) exist get all attribute values also.

thank you.

Comment: you probably need to use `.click()` because it's a click event, not a keyboard key event.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the ID of the element that fired an event using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event-using-jquery)

Comment: yeah we can use but here we should specify input tag then only it is working thank you ADIL

Comment: but my requirement is keyboard event only thank you biala

Answer (score 4):

According to [jquery: get id from class selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470729/jquery-get-id-from-class-selector)

```
$('.clsName').click(function() {
    alert( this.id );
});
```

I have tested it properly.

Comment: +1 for just using plain `this.id` here when jQuery's `$(this).attr("id")` is two more function calls and an object creation and adds no value.

Comment: thank you i have used this in alert but showing empty alert

Comment: Have you given Id to your div?

Comment: here you are using click event you can get but where as my side keyup

Comment: yeah i have given everything and also i am using some values also inside my method i want to change value dynamically which is clicked field

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
 $(this).attr('id');
```

using javascript

```
 this.id;
```

Full code:

```
$(".clsName").keyup(function () {
   $(this).attr('id');
});
```

**Update:**

You are having the dom:

```
<div class="clsName">
 <input type="number" name="first" id="first">
 <input type="number" name="second" id="second">
 <input type="number" name="third" id="third">
```

That means you have used wrong selector to target input. it should be:

```
$(".clsName input").keyup(function () {
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wabeL/)**

Comment: thank you but i have used this but getting id giving undefined

Comment: Please show the html you have

Comment: @kalyangudla: This should work. can you share the dom and place where you are binding the event.

Comment: alert($(this).attr('id'));

Comment: <div class="clsName">                                            <input type="number" name="first" id="first">                     <input type="number" name="second" id="second">                       <input type="number" name="third" id="third">                     </div>

Comment: @kalyangudla: see the updated answerd.

Answer (score 2):

Use `this.id` in pure javascript and use   **[input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384218/jquery-input-event)**  event handler

```
    $(".clsName input").on("input",function () {
    console.log(this.id);
   });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/J4V5C/13/)

It's not quite an alias for keyup because keyup will fire even if the key does nothing (for example: pressing and then releasing the Control key will trigger a keyup event).

A good way to think about it is like this: it's an event that triggers whenever the input changes. This includes -- but is not limited to -- pressing keys which modify the input (so, for example, Ctrl by itself will not trigger the event, but Ctrl-V to paste some text will), selecting an auto-completion option, Linux-style middle-click paste, drag-and-drop, and lots of other things.

**[more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384218/jquery-input-event)**

Comment: thank you so much we should specify input also then it is coming. thank you very much MR.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.attr()` in jquery.

```
$(".clsName").keyup(function () {
     $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Comment: i used getting undefined .i have doubt how you are using this because we are not declaring na

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".clsName").keyup(function () {
var id=$(this).attr('id');
});
```

Comment: how we can use this with out we are declaring anything . thank you

Answer (score 0):

as you have written "**how to find which id i have clicked". so to get the click id , you should use click event not keyup**

```
$(".clsName").on('click',function () {
   var getclickedID=$(this).attr('id');
});
```